# How many tabs are open in chrome browser? (Above 100)

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser-tabs

When the number of tabs reaches 100, the tab counter turns into a smiley face like so :D

I wish to know how many tabs are open, without doing the manual count. Is there a way?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more technical approach is to use `adb` and `chrome_devtools_remote` to get a list of ALL open tabs
[image: The list of tabs example]

Short how-to:

1. Install an Android SDK, we only need the `adb`.
2. Connect your phone to your computer via a cable.
3. In a terminal, run this to get a list of connected devices:

```
./adb devices -l
```

4. Run this:

```
./adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

5. Open http://localhost:9222/json/list on your computer to get a JSON list of your open Chrome tabs.
6. In short, the count of the `{` characters in the JSON is the number of tabs open in your Android Chrome.

Read how to do this in full at ["When you never close tabs on your mobile Chrome browser" by Marcin Piczkowski, in Dev.to](https://dev.to/piczmar_0/when-you-never-close-tabs-on-your-mobile-chrome-browser-2boj)

Comment: This is a bit technical but very useful, as it allows you to export a list of all the urls and mass-close them on the phone. I tried it with success a few months ago.

Answer (score 11):

This is an [Easter egg](http://www.cnet.com/news/two-easter-eggs-hatch-in-chrome-for-android/) coded 4 years ago

From this [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/general/guide-how-tabs-chrome-past-100-t2934266)- you need a *rooted device*  ( you can't access `/data/data/` without root )

> 1. Download a root explorer capable app such as ES file explorer
> 2. Navigate to chromes profile directory, mine was at /data/data/com.android.chrome
> 3. Open the app_tabs folder
> 4. You should now see a single folder labeled "0"
> 5. Select it and open its properties, under file count deduct 1 and that will be how many tabs you have open currently, deduct 1 because 1 file in there is only an overall tab state file

Verified on my device  ( Moto X Play, 6.0.1, Chrome `52.0. 2743.91`) when the tabs open are 4 = `Files` (5) minus one

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Google Chrome on a Galaxy Z Fold4 (as of April 20th, 2023):

1. Tap the "Switch or close tabs" button (i.e. the ":D" button)
2. At the top right, tap the vertical ellipses button "⋮"
3. Tap the "Select tabs" menu item
4. Tap the "⋮" button again
5. "Select all"

At the top left, look at one of the shocks of your life:
[image: Screenshot showing the 1,912 currently open tabs on this device. Definitely a shock tham I'm not proud of]

Comment: I've also verified it also counts tabs in groups.

Comment: Works for me on PIxel 6 phone as well. Thanks!

Comment: Works as of 2024 on an old android 9 tablet running chrome 120 with 2373 open tabs 

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a way to see how many tabs you have open without rooting the device or doing any other things people are suggesting

Just simply, enable Talkback mode in accessibility features. Then when you hover (if you have Bluetooth mouse enabled) or tap the tab icon (with your finger) (the :D), it will tell you how many tabs you have open. Like on mine, it said 713 tabs open.

(warning, with grouped tabs (more than 1 tab in group) it counts that as 1 tab it doesn't count them all. so if you have 7 groups of 100 tabs open it will only say 7(show too))

Comment: Does this still work? For me it didn't say a number. However when I had TalkBack on, the tab grid became a simple scrollable list, so it was much easier to feel the amount.

Comment: @TWiStErRob it is no longer working for me. It worked for a few years, but sometime in the last 2 years I think it stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

### How to count your open Chrome tabs in Android by looking at your synced Android tabs (done from a computer)

This is really dumb that Google won't just show the number in Chrome on the phone instead of showing `:D` past `99` tabs, but this is the best I can come up with. (GOOGLE, PLEASE FIX THIS!)

Note: if someone knows how to use the Google APIs I wonder if they can script this and count this automatically!

1. On a *computer*, NOT on a phone, go to your "other devices" Chrome history, and find your phone device (for me it is "Pixel 2"). Note: for this to work, you must be signed into the same Google account on both your computer's Chrome browser as well as in your phone.

   1. In your Chrome browser, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, then on the left side, click "Tabs from other devices"
   2. OR, in your computer's Chrome browser, just navigate straight to here: `chrome://history/syncedTabs`
2. You'll see something like this: [image]
3. Find the location to the left of the first icon next to the first link in the list. This location is marked in yellow in the image below. Left click on this location and drag right to highlight a word or two, as shown here: [image]
4. Now manually scroll down the page until you find the *last link* in the list for this device (where this device is your phone, or course). Once there, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> at the end of the last row to highlight all the way down to the last row, as shown here. I clicked at the location marked in yellow: [image].
5. Now, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to copy-paste all of this into your favorite text editor/code editor which shows line numbers. I like [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/). I think it's great!
6. Voilá! The number of lines you have is equal to the number of tabs you have open in Chrome on this device--which is my Google Pixel 2! I have `494` open tabs: [image]. Indeed, this is way too many. Next question I have: how do I mass-close them?: [How do I close all, or many at once, Chrome tabs on Android on a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232569/how-do-i-close-all-or-many-at-once-chrome-tabs-on-android-on-a-phone)

If someone can script this process, please do! You may even be able to make it a Javascript bookmarklet or something which is runnable in Chrome on a PC or phone? I don't really know Javascript, but here are some of my favorite bookmarklets I use regularly in GitHub code review, for example, if this helps get you started writing bookmarklets to solve this problem: https://gist.github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/0a788876da1386ca0daecbe78b4feb44.

Comment: According to my technique above, I just closed **504** more tabs! But, when I used the close all tabs option in Chrome on my phone, it said it closed **665** tabs. I think my phone was counting _tab groups_ too, so **504 tabs** + **161 tab groups** = **665 total**, which is what the phone reported when I mass-closed them.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the answer of Mat, if you have a stylus (like Samsung Galaxy Note), you can also hover on the tabs [:D] button to see your open tabs count.
[image: Chrome tabs on hover]

###### Update 2022-10-01

This now shows "Switch or close tabs", it doesn't show the tab count anymore.

Answer (score 1):

With some experimenting, swiping and manual counting, I've found that swiping will move a max of 25 tabs each time (depending on how strong you swipe). I think this is a programmed constant, although I haven't checked if the code is available to confirm the number.

My shortcut for counting tabs has become to swipe from one end to the other, counting the number of swipes, and multiplying by 25, giving a good enough approximation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new way to find number of tabs now - that doesn't require complicated steps or connecting to a computer:

[image: Tab View Actions]

1. Select top right action
2. Click on the select tabs
3. Then click on select all from top right menu again

You get the total tab count

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The "Select tabs" option is not there on my phone. Which phone/Android version are you using?

Comment: Hey, I am on OnePlus 9R, Android 13, Chrome 120.0.6099.43

Answer (score 0):

Another way u can use on every operating system you want, is to [check google account sync review](https://chrome.google.com/sync) . It will show you how many tabs you have opened on all devices you have this account on (if more than one device). Shows you bookmarks and some other information.
Anyway i don't know why but i think it doesn't count chrome tab folders because i used another way before (from answers here, using google select all tabs.) And it was different from that. Anyway i hope it helps but the better a easier way is what Mohammad Badrah said up there in answers.